# How to remove space bottom mat-form-field

Tags: angular-material, angular7

[image]

I use angular 7 with angular material and i want to remove the space bottom as you can see. I tried many way but no sucess.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can add this in your css

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper{
   margin-bottom: -1.25em;
}
```

> **NOTE:** As you remove the space you cannot put `<mat-hint>hint</mat-hint>` or `<mat-error>error</mat-error>` properly.
> Error and hint get inside the form-field.

**Without using `::ng-deep`( for Angular 8 )**

Turn off encapsulation of your component inside which you change the padding.

You can do this by

```js
import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['example.component.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Wrap the component you want to style in a custom class. So it wont affect any other `mat-form-field` components.
Let's wrap this with with `my-form-field` class for now

```html
<mat-form-field class="my-form-field">
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
.my-form-field .mat-form-field-wrapper {
      margin-bottom: -1.25em;
}
```

You can add these css in global stylesheet without turning off view encapsulation. But the more elegant method is the above one.

Comment: Use !important othervise it won't work. => margin-bottom: -1.25em !important;

Comment: You don't need to put !important for this to work. since there is no margin-bottom in `.mat-form-field-wrapper` styles written by Angular material and even if they had any margin-bottom styling (not !important by default) because we are wrapping `mat-form-field` with a custom class, in here for example 'my-form-field'

Comment: @Isuru Dilshan If it is still not working. Can you provide me an example in Stackblitz or any other online IDE.

Comment: I work with Angular 10.0.3. Without !important it didn't work. But your answer is the only answer I found to fix this issue. Thanks for that

Comment: and also the latest indigo-pink.css do have following .mat-form-field--wrapper. This is the code  **.mat-form-field-wrapper {
 padding-bottom: 1.34375em
}**

Comment: I did not meant it don't have a css for `.mat-form-field-wrapper` I meant it does not have the css with any margin-bottom styling.
And I am really confused why it doesn't work with Angular 10. I had used this with latest Angular material. Kindly check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsrbhw?file=src/app/form-field-overview-example.html) which uses latest angular material.

Comment: Now I get it. I miss understanding the padding and margin-bottom. You are correct

Comment: Great!!! Congrats!!! Thanks!!!. It works. Plus, do not affect the rest of the application. It is applied only to the components included with the specific class *.my-form-field* applied. It should be explained as a pattern in some article.

Answer (score 149):

For anyone reading this in 2023: Angular 15 now added a new property to the form fields: subscriptSizing.

If you add `subscriptSizing="dynamic"` to `mat-form-field`, it'll remove the space until an error or hint actually needs to get displayed and only then expands. This causes a layout shift, but depending on your use case it is probably the better option than manually adding a margin as suggested (and necessary up to version 14) before.

For reference see https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#SubscriptSizing

You can also specify this globally as default via the MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS injection token; see https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldDefaultOptions

```js
// in main.ts (Angular 15+)
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        subscriptSizing: 'dynamic'
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this property to all form fields globally?

Comment: @mbauer: didn't test it as I don't have access to my work device right now, but I'm pretty confident, you could just derive a custom component from the mat-form-field, set this property on it and exchange all usages of mat-form-field in your code with your inherited component.

Comment: @mbauer Yes, you can add it in the MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS in your app.module

Comment: Thanks @MattHarrison! I supplemented my answer with this info. 

Comment: So for anyone else also thinking that they can update to Angular 15 to get this new feature and finally stop wasting hours fiddling ccs overrides to the material components: In Angular 15, most if not all material components have been deprecated.  And long story short, despite there being automated tool for migration, it's not at all a trivial effort to accommodate this change (for our site at least).  And many other packages with Angular dependencies such as the mat theme generator have not had time to add Angular 15 support, so currently the material conversion tool breaks those.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's up to date and actually works. None of the other css tricks worked for me. I'm using Angular 15.

Comment: This is the best way to solve the issue. I'm using Angular material ^15.2.8

Comment: It is more portable and safer to make changes in `app.module.ts` instead of `main.ts`. You App related changes should all happen inside of the `src/app/` folder unless it has to do with changing environment, assets, global styles, typescript and angular settings, etc. During an upgrade process, Angular might change the structure of `main.ts` and you will loose your providers' settings.

Comment: it's not working for mat-checkbox though

Answer (score 50):

Try the following:

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-bottom: -1.25em">
```

(You can follow the discussion about this extra bottom space here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7975)

Answer (score 16):

In angular 9, I was able to remove the gaps only by adding the following into the component.scss (the other answers didn't worked in my case):

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper{
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also, I'm using appearance="outline", for other appearances, it will probably be necessary to change other css classes and properties, since it may have other elements.

Answer (score 8):

In Angular Material 15, you can use  `subscriptSizing="dynamic"`.

```html
<mat-form-field class="w-full" appearance="outline" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
</mat-form-filed>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

My solution was to use an additional class.

HTML:

```html
    <mat-form-field class="no-padding">
        <input type="number" matInput placeholder="Speed" [ngModel]="speed"
               (ngModelChange)="onSpeedChange('speed', $event)"/>
      </mat-form-field>
```

SCSS:

```scss
    .no-padding {
      .mat-form-field-wrapper {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
      }
    }
```

The `!important` keyword is unfortunately necessary as it will otherwise just pull in the default instead.

Comment: I had to put this into `styles.scss` instead of `my.component.scss` to get this to work with angular 11

Answer (score 4):

or simply:

**html**

```html
<mat-form-field class="no-bottom">
...
</mat-form-field>
```

**css**

```css
.no-bottom {
  margin-bottom: -1.25em !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was trying padding-bottom: 0 but it didn't work, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I test by Angular 10, this works:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper{
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also, if you need to apply ONLY on a special field, define a class:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="no-wrapper">
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
```

And put class name in your css:

```
    :host ::ng-deep .no-wrapper .mat-form-field-wrapper{
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to remove bottom space of mat-form-filed by using following css in style.scss

```
.mat-form-field-wrapper{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the following template:

```js
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="compact-input">
  <mat-label>Test</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

and the following SCSS:

```css
.compact-input {
  .mat-form-field-flex {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  .mat-form-field-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .mat-form-field-underline {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Only tested for `standard` appearance though.

Don't forget to add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component.
If you put the SCSS in the global styles, you might need to add some `!important`'s.

Answer (score 2):

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. You can achieve the same by setting the `subscriptSizing=dynamic` option on the form field. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75107066/5470544

Comment: @JSONDerulo there could be a custom control which uses `mat-form-field` (or whatnot) under the hood. In this case you cannot set properties of the element you don't have direct access to. So I would not call this solution "poor". Sometimes it is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Christoph142's answer, With Angular Material 17+ In your *.module file, add the following:

```
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,MatFormFieldModule} from @angular/material/form-field';
...
@NgModule({
providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { subscriptSizing: 'dynamic' },
  },
 ],
})
```

[View documentation for details](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants)

Answer (score 2):

use this subscriptSizing="dynamic" in the mat-form-field, it's worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-form-field-infix{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    flex: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent !important;
}
```

you can add important in css

Answer (score 1):

You can add height:4em to mat-form-field as such:

```
    <mat-form-field
        class="height-4em"
        appearance="outline"
        >
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use ::ng-deep 
this is simple.. add this to your css file

```
mat-form-field{
    margin-bottom: -1.25em
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
Adding a custom class to mat-form-field and targeting the .mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align class to give its display property a value of none did the trick in my case.

```
::ng-deep .my-form-field .mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align {
    display: none !important;
}
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <ng-container *ngIf="currentPage === 1">
    <mat-form-field class="my-form-field" style="padding:10px;">
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to utilize the class name of subscript-wrapper:

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    height: 0;
}
```

That way you can easily remove the bottom space from your mat-form-fields easily by selecting via appropiate CSS queries.

Placed above CSS rules in the components SCSS file would result on all used mat-form-fields inside the component the bottom space to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the font size with material theme you will get smaller input

```
$typography: mat-typography-config(
  $input: mat-typography-level(14px, 1.125, 400),
);

@include mat-core($typography);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem w/ `mat-fab` button when using it together w/ `mat-spinnner`. Whenever the spinner would be "activated" the elements around would shift down. The problem was w/ `.mat-fab .mat-button-wrapper` which comes from an embedded wrapping `span` element of `mat-spinner` after rendering.

Setting,

```
::ng-deep .mat-fab .mat-button-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

solved the problem. The `vertical-align` is not needed but aligns nicely the spinner w/in the `mat-fab` button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]With Angular 16

```
   .mat-mdc-form-field-bottom-align::before {
      display: none !important;
    }
```

**but set it in** style.css on the root of the folder, not in css of the component..

Answer (score 0):

For material 17, this worked for me

```
.mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
    height: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer set property directly, without :deep
(solution for Angular Material 16+)

```
 .mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
   display: none;
 }
```